# What does this dash warning mean? 2006 BMW 325i

Tags: bmw, warning-light

[image: dash warning light]

I couldn't find this symbol in my manual. I was hoping someone else knew what that light meant? I'm not a mechanic, I would just rather diagnose the issue myself than take it to the dealership (especially since it's an old vehicle).

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Just by looking at it, it might have something to do with the sunroof (moonroof ... the big hole in the roof, thingymajigger).

Comment: I used to have a car (not a BMW) with a similar thing. There were two "open" positions for the sunroof, one of which was only meant for use when the vehicle was parked. If you started the engine in that state, and you got a warning that if you drove off you were likely to leave the sunroof behind you on the road.

Comment: It is indeed a sunroof warning. I couldn't find more than that . Maybe sunroof not locked?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This seems to be a fairly common problem with these and it's easy to reset.
1) Close all door's and lock the car, now unlock and enter
2) Insert the key fob
3) Press engine start without actually starting the car(no breaks or clutch)
4) Push up on the sunroof button for ~30-40 seconds
5) While holding the button thesunroof should cycle through opening and closing itself
6) Release the button and enjoy no more error pictures

Comment: I just love these simple and intuitive procedures car makers implement in their systems.